# Rxjava Scheduler.trampoline versus concatmap

Tags: rx-java2

It seems based on documentation that Scheduler.trampoline assures that elements emit first-in first-out (ie in order). it also seems that the point of concat map is to assure that everything is lined up appropriately and then emitted. So I was wondering if there was every a point in applying subscribeOn./.observeOn(Scheduler.trampoline()) and then doing afterwards concatmap operator as opposed to a regular mapping operating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a point. Take this example:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
    .flatMap(
        a -> {
          if (a < 3) {
            return Observable.just(a).delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          } else {
            return Observable.just(a);
          }
        })
    .doOnNext(
        a -> System.out.println("Element: " + a + ", on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
    .subscribe();
```

Here's the output:

```
Element: 3, on: main
Element: 4, on: main
Element: 5, on: main
Element: 1, on: RxComputationScheduler-1
Element: 2, on: RxComputationScheduler-2
```

What's happening here is 1 and 2 reach the `flatMap` operator in sequence. But now, the inner streams for these elements is delayed by 3 seconds. Note that `flatMap` eagerly `subscribes` to the inner streams. That is, it does not wait for one stream to finish (with `onComplete`) before `subscribing` to the next inner stream (which is what concatMap does).

So the inner streams of 1 and 2 are delayed by 3 seconds. You can say that this is an external I/O call that is taking a bit of time. Meanwhile, the next 3 elements (3,4,5) enter the `flatMap` and their streams finish immediately. That's why you see  the sequence maintained in the output.

Then 3 seconds get over and elements 1 and 2 are emitted. Note that there's no guarantee that 1 would come before 2.

Now replace `flatMap` with `concatMap` and you'll see that the sequence is maintained:

```
Element: 1, on: RxComputationScheduler-1
Element: 2, on: RxComputationScheduler-2
Element: 3, on: RxComputationScheduler-2
Element: 4, on: RxComputationScheduler-2
Element: 5, on: RxComputationScheduler-2
```

Why? Because that's how `concatMap` works. Element 1 comes, and is used in an I/O call. It'll take 3 seconds before the inner stream corresponding to its inner stream emits an `onComplete`. The inner stream corresponding the remaining elements are not subscribed to by `concatMap` until the first stream emits an onComplete. As soon as it does, the next stream (`Observable.just(2).delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`) is `subscribed` to, and so on. So you can see how the order is maintained.

The thing you need to remember about these two operators is: `flatMap` eagerly `subscribes` to the inner streams, as and when the elements arrive. On the other hand, `concatMap` waits for one stream to finish before it `subscribes` to the next one. That's why you can't make parallel calls with `concatMap`.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you so much

Comment: I upvoted, but my reputation is not high enough yet to have it seen :(

Comment: Haha no problem. You can accept the answer with the tick mark if you found it useful. And keep asking questions and answering them.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. `trampoline` essentially executes work on one of the threads calling its `Worker.schedule` method in a FIFO order.

In case of `Observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())`, it will be the thread subscribing so there is no practical effect applying it.

In case of `Observable.observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())`, it will be the thread signaling items so there is no practical effect there either.

`concatMap` executes the mapper function either on the thread signaling the upstream items or the thread the inner `Observable` completes. The operator essentially has a built-in trampolining already so upstream items and downstream completion is not overlapping. In 3.x, there will be an [overload](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#concatMap-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function-int-io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Scheduler-) taking a `Scheduler`, for which `Schedulers.trampoline()` would have no practical effect either.

The best use case for `Schedulers.trampoline()` is in unit tests where you don't need asynchrony. Therefore, you either parameterize your `subscribeOn`/`observeOn` usages or use a scheduler hook and replace the standard schedulers:

```java
 RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(s -> Schedulers.trampoline());
 RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(s -> Schedulers.trampoline());
 RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler(s -> Schedulers.trampoline());
```

then once you are done,

```java
 RxJavaPlugins.reset();
```